# how to exclude some numbers from a list

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import random
from networkx.utils import powerlaw_sequence


W=powerlaw_sequence(100,exponent=2.5)

random.choice(W)
```

What if I want the numbers of this sequence to be any number except zero? or any number in a specific range? so that the smallest value is 1, e.g.. Or even to assign this condition when choosing the random number from the sequence.

Neither powerlaw_sequence(100,exponent=2.0,range(1,20)) nor powerlaw_sequence(100,exponent=2.0,xmin=1) work. Thank you

Comment: Would it be a problem if `W` had less than 100 entries?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know numpy, so perhaps there is another possible solution, but the following should work:

```
W = [x for x in powerlaw_sequence(100,exponent=2.5) if x != 0]
```

However, this reduces the length of `W` by the number of elements that are filtered out because of the condition `x != 0`.

Comment: @ Tim Pietzcker Thank you very much :)

Comment: Or you could use `filter` if you wanted something you could reuse.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for a Zipf sequence?

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: nx.utils.zipf_sequence(10,alpha=2.5)
Out[2]: [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8]
```

http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.utils.random_sequence.zipf_sequence.html#networkx.utils.random_sequence.zipf_sequence